# Let V be real finite-dimensional vector space and $A \in L(V)$ such that $ A^{3} -A^{2} + A - I = 0.$ Prove that $\det A = 1$.

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be real finite-dimensional vector space and $$A \in L(V)$$ such that 
>   $$ A^{3} -A^{2} + A - I = 0.$$ Prove that $$\det A = 1$$.

First of all, I wrote the equation in this form
$$ A^{3} -A^{2} + A - I = (A^{2} + I)(A - I) = 0,$$
 so $\sigma(A)= \{1\}$ or $ \sigma(A^{2}) = \{-1\}$ and $$\det ((A^{2} + I)(A - I)) = \det(A^{2} + I)\det(A - I) = \det0 = 0.$$
From here further I am stuck. Any hint helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know about minimal polynomials, you can conclude that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(A^2+I)(A-I)$, so it is either $(A^2+I)$ or $A-I$ or $(A^2+I)(A-I)$, hence the spectrum of $A$ is a subset of $\{1,-i,i\}$. If $i$ or $-i$ is in the spectrum, then the other must be as well, and with the same multiplicity since $A$ acts on a real vector space. In any case the product of the eigenvalues is $1$.

Comment: Can you just explain how will the product of eigenvalues be 1?

Comment: You are looking at a product of the form $1^b (i)^a  (-i)^a = 1^b (-(i^2))^a= 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The eigevalues of $A$ are contained in $\{1,i,-i\}$.

If the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$  then $det(A)=1$.

otherwise the  eigenvalues are  $1,i,-i$. Consider $A$ has a complex matrix. If $A(u)=iu, A(\bar u)=\bar i u=-u$, we deduce that $V=E\oplus F\oplus G$ where the restriction of $A$ to $E$ is upper triangular with $1$ on the diagonal,

The restriction of $A$ to $F$ is upper triangular with $i$ on the diagonal,

The restriction of $A$ to $G$ is upper triangular with $-i$ on the diagonal and $\bar F=G$ this implies that $F$ and $G$ have the same dimension and $det(A)=1$.